# c++ Help designing class ConstArray and Array which represent a kind of dynamic array of int values

Tags: c++, arrays

I think I will first just say the entire question and then comment on my problems below it.

Specifications
You should design two classes ConstArray and Array which represent a kind of dynamic array of int values (similar to the standard libraries valarray template).

ConstArray
The class ConstArray should be designed so that it behaves like a constant array whose contents cannot be changed. Memory is to be allocated and deallocated dynamically. The size and the contents of the array are determined when an object of the class is constructed. At least the following members should be implemented:

```
size_type, element_type
```

- public type definitions (typedef) of the corresponding types.

```
size()
```

- returns the number of elements of the array.

```
operator [] (int) const
```

- returns the value element of the k-th element.

A copy constructor performing a deep copy operation.

A constructor that can be used to initialize the array with data from a C-style array.

A destructor that frees any dynamically allocated memory.

**Array**
The class Array is to be derived from ConstArray. In addition to that classes functionality, the size and the contents of Array objects can be changed. The following additional members should be provided

```
operator=(const ConstArray&)
```

- assignment of a ConstArray to an Array

```
operator=(const Array&)
```

- assignment of an Array

```
operator[](int)
```

- returning a reference to the k-th element

```
resize()
```

-Changes the number of elements in the array. The current contents of the array may be destroyed by this operation.

**Now for my problems**
I do not really get how to implement size_type and element_type into this. I understand that they are typedefs, so basically alias, but from that I do not really understand.

What is a "deep copy operation"?

What is a C-style array? I do not really understand how to set up the constructor to initialize the size of array. Where exactly do I determine the size? It doesn't say to ask the user to input it or anything.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not really get how to implement size_type and element_type into this.

As you said, they are just typedefs.  You can define types in the scope of the class, for example:

```
class ConstArray {
public:
    typedef int size_type;
};
```

After that you can use `size_type` whenever you want to get or return the size of the array.

> What is a "deep copy operation"?

As you allocate the data memory dynamically, you will end up with a pointer to the array data (of type `element_type*`).  A *shallow copy* would just copy the pointer, so that you end up with two objects referring to the same shared data (dangerous, as it is unclear who is responsible to release the memory).  A *deep copy*, on the other hand, would allocate a new array, and copy all the data, so that you end up with two objects that have their own data array each.

> What is a C-style array?

A pointer to the data, along with the size of the array.  In your assignment, implement a constructor `ConstArray(element_type* data, size_type size)`.

> Where exactly do I determine the size?

You need to ask for it, using a separate constructor argument, see above.  Whoever uses the constructor also knows the size of the existing (!) data array.